# Why was Ares contradictory to common Mythology?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman

In Wonder Woman, especially during the fight with Ares there were a few things that stuck out as strange.

1. Ares was able to wield and use lightning, commonly known as [Zeus' power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeus), not Ares.
2. Ares was able to use telekinetic abilities to throw and manipulate things, contradictory to his known fighting styles as the God of War. "ARES was the Olympian god of war, battlelust and manliness."
3. Ares supposedly killed all the Gods, which is [again contradictory](http://www.ancient.eu/Ares/), although he did fight notable people such as Hercules.

**Is there any reason why things like this were chosen?** Perhaps a director's quote on why, a bit from the comics etc.

Comment: Because comics don't follow **common mythology**? There might be a valid question here (although not for this site) if the movie was different to the comic mythology here but otherwise...I don't think so.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call these things contradictory to common Mythology... There is nothing in Mythology that expressly said Ares could not wield lightning. Seeing as he was Zues' son it's more likely he had the capability to due so, but simply was not know for it. The same reasoning stands for the other 2 points.

Comment: Wasn't sure if this was on topic or not, if it's not I'll freely delete it no problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't know much about the comic's mythology, if it doesn't differ that much than I can just remove this if it's off topic.

Comment: Well, I'm not putting this as an answer, since this is just "my" interpretations, but I don't really think superhero movies are caring at all about the fidelity mythologies (7 feet tall Ice Giants in Thor, anyone?). This is just to prove my point, in WW: (Ignore the obvious comic tone as it gets the point across) [The New ‘Wonder Woman’ Is Really A Story About Jesus](https://thefederalist.com/2017/06/05/new-wonder-woman-really-story-jesus/).  Still, I did enjoy this movie.

Comment: DC comics are only loosely basing their mythos on actual Greek mythology, they take giant artistic licenses. Then the DCEU take advantage of their artistic license even more when creating the cinematic counterpart to the comics, distancing the on-screen "Greek mythology" even further from actual Greek mythology.

Comment: Because this film is not a mythology film but a comics book fiction

Comment: OP is clearly asking for word of God, nothing about this is opinion based.

Comment: Hmm I can understand this being closed. But for opinion based I'm not so sure.

Comment: So, you have character that is acting out 3100 years after the myths about him that you are referring to.  If he's truly an Olympian and not just a myth, is it surprising that something may have happened in those intervening 3100 years since the myths were established/told/recorded to alter that status quo? Or that ancient myths might not be 100% perfectly accurate about a being those people clearly did not fully understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

Taking into consideration that there are no direct answers about this by any of the people in charge of the movie or any in universe explanation about it. But lets consider some all-round knowledge, mainly the comics and Greek Mythology. Some of it you will have to accept that the comics already are very different from the Mythology since they have their own universe.

- The lightning could either be weather harness or actually Zeus' thunderbolt, since he is dead.
- Ares is able to have telekinetic control over every weapon in the comics.
- The killing of every god was a DCEU (DC Extended Universe) choice, which is weird.

  - DCEU are the movies produced by DC starting with *Man of Steel*, 2013

---

### LONG ANSWER

### 1. The Lightning

In my point of view, there are 2 main possibilities to go on WHY and HOW he was able to harness lightning:

- **The comic book explanation**

According to [Ares's profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ares_(DC_Comics)), he has many abilities other than just fighting, such as Energy Projection and Weather Manipulation. In my opinion, he could just have harnessed the natural lightning, and not used Zeus's signature weapon. (If I recall, the weather changed during there fight also. Correct me if I'im wrong.) Also, this could be an Ares thing that he used exactly to mock Zeus (who is dead).

- **The true Zeus' lightning**

Here is the origin of Zeus Power from his [birth story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeus):

> After reaching manhood, Zeus forced Cronus to disgorge first the stone
>   (which was set down at Pytho under the glens of Parnassus to be a sign
>   to mortal men, the Omphalos) then his siblings in reverse order of
>   swallowing. In some versions, Metis gave Cronus an emetic to force him
>   to disgorge the babies, or Zeus cut Cronus's stomach open. Then Zeus
>   released the brothers of Cronus, the Gigantes, the Hecatonchires and
>   the Cyclopes, from their dungeon in Tartarus, killing their guard,
>   Campe.
>
> As a token of their appreciation, **the Cyclopes gave him thunder and
>   the thunderbolt, or lightning, which had previously been hidden by
>   Gaia.**
>
> Together, Zeus, his brothers and sisters, along with the Gigantes,
>   Hecatonchires and Cyclopes overthrew Cronus and the other Titans, in
>   the combat called the Titanomachy. The defeated Titans were then cast
>   into a shadowy underworld region known as Tartarus. Atlas, one of the
>   titans who fought against Zeus, was punished by having to hold up the
>   sky.

(My emphasis)

So now we may assume a few things by this. We know that Zeus' signature thunderbolt is his weapon, not an inherent power. In this particular DCEU, Zeus is dead and Ares was the only god alive of the Greek Pantheon for a while. Isn't it capable that he obtained Zeus' thunderbolt during this time?

---

### 2. Telekinetic Abilities

This, as explained above, actually is very capable that he would use. As described also in his profile, Ares in the comics has the telekinetic power over every weapon (What defines a weapon is really vague). Also, telekinesis is actually a very common power for powerful beings in movies.

### 3. Killed All The Gods

This was an DCEU choice. This does not happen in Greek Mythology neither the Comics. Actually Wonder Woman usually fights other Greek Gods such as Circe. I really don't know what they were thinking.

Comment: I appreciate the answer! Makes sense for a lot of it.. and I'm not at all familiar with DCEU.

Comment: @Kuro DCEU Is the Extended Universe of the movies. You may understand its Greek Mythology as an adaptation of the Mythos that was already adapted in the Comics. So of course it will not be all that accurate. Feel free to question anything that you read in my answer.

Comment: Random downvotes... Nice.

Comment: @LeonFreire Yeah... that was a effort answer, and not a bad one. Would be helpful to clear up exactly what DCEU is vs the comic's universe. I was pretty confused at first.

Comment: Maybe the film maker had to kill the other gods to increase the drama and make sure everybody understands that Wonder Woman is mankind's last hope, no other good to rely on  is left.

Comment: @ViggyNash Thank you for the pointer. Hope its clearer now.

Comment: In the comic Bacchus aka Deadface, by Eddie Campbell, a character named the Eyeball Kid (grandson of Argus) kills Zeus and inherits his lightning bolts.  It's a trope that'd been used before.